# How can you derive De Morgan's Law?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Can someone help me prove De Morgan's Law. In my logic class we are using a very basic set of rules for derivations and I can't for the life of me figure out how to prove the law with them. It's not homework; my TA gave me extra problems to practice for the midterm. By the way, I know [this article](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28324/proving-de-morgans-laws-for-quantifiers) is asking the same question, but I do not understand the notation so I don't know if they're restricted to the same rules.

Prove ***p&q <-> ~(~pV~q)*** and/or ***pvq <-> ~(~p&~q)*** using only these rules: &Intro/Elim, vIntro/Elim, ~Intro/Elim, ->Intro/Elim, <->Intro/Elim. Please use this notation as well.

As far as I can tell, the proof should look like this:

```
|pVq            Hyp

|-

||~p&~q         Hyp[for ~Intro]

||-

||~p            &Elim[~p^~q]

||q             **I'm not sure how to prove that ~p -> q with the limited rules**

||~q            &Elim[~p^~q]

|~(~p&~q)       ~Intro[~p&~q, q, ~q]
```

Comment: The other question is proving it for *quantified logic* which is going to be a bit different and harder.

Comment: Many people here may be able to help, but this might be better answered on the Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track.

From the assumption [a] : **¬p ∧ ¬q** you correctly derive **¬p** and **¬q** by ∧-Elimination :

1) **p ∨ q** --- premise

2) **¬p ∧ ¬q** --- assumed [a]

3) **¬p** --- from 2) by ∧-Elim

4) **¬q** --- from 2) by ∧-Elim

5) **p** --- assumed [b] for ∨-Elimination

6) **⊥** --- contradiction, from 3) and 5)

7) **q** --- assumed [c] for ∨-Elimination

8) **⊥** --- contradiction, from 4) and 7)

9) **⊥** --- from 1), 5)-6) and 7)-8) by ∨-Elimination, discharging [b] and [c]

> 10) **¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)** --- from 2) and 9) by ¬-Introduction, dicharging the assumption [a]
>
> **(p ∨ q) → ¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)** --- from 1) and 10) by →-Introduction.

---

In order to prove :

> **¬(¬p ∧ ¬q) → (p ∨ q)**,

we need :

1) **¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)** --- premise

2) **¬(p ∨ q)** --- assumed [a]

3) **p** --- assumed [b]

4) **p ∨ q** --- by ∨-Introduction

5) **¬p** --- from 3) by ¬-Introduction and the contradiction between 2) and 4), discharging [b]

6) **q** --- assumed [c]

7) **p ∨ q** --- by ∨-Introduction

8) **¬q** --- from 6) by ¬-Introduction and the contradiction between 2) and 7), discharging [c]

9) **¬p ∧ ¬q** --- from 5) and 8) by ∧-Introduction

10) **¬¬(p ∨ q)** --- from 2) by ¬-Introduction and the contradiction between 1) and 9), discharging [a]

> 11) **(p ∨ q)** --- from 10) by [Double Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)-Elimination
>
> > **¬(¬p ∧ ¬q) → (p ∨ q)** --- from 1) and 11) by →Introduction.

Comment: I was a little confused at first by reading the proof of **(p ∨ q) → ¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)** but actually seeing the second proof helped so much. We were given ~40 practice problems over the weekend, and most of the problems I was stuck on came down to needing De Morgens proved at some point, which I think I get now. Thanks!