# Are these two propositions equivalent?

Tags: logic

Are the propositions "Everything happens for a reason", and "Nothing happens without a reason" logically equivalent?

Comment: i think the answer you have is fine, though you may want to be careful you don't equivocate 'reason' or indeed 'nothing' when interpreting it

Comment: Add a truth table to your post for each statement. Are the two tables identical?

Comment: In classical logic, yes. ¬∃¬R(x) is obtained from∀x R(x) by applying the [De Morgan's law for quantifiers](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/28324/9148), which works in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

We may introduce two predicates, *thinghood*, τ(x), and *happening for a reason*, ρ(x). Then we can translate the statements into the standard first-order language as follows:

‘Everything happens for a reason’

∀x(τ(x) → ρ(x)) ↔ ∀x(¬τ(x) ∨ ρ(x))

‘Nothing happens without a reason’

¬∃x(τ(x) ∧ ¬ρ(x)) ↔ ∀x(¬τ(x) ∨ ρ(x))

We see that they are logically equivalent. However, the translation hinges on the idea of *thinghood*, and the related issue of **quantifying over absolute generality** is a matter of metaphysical dispute.

Comment: Thinghood... I don't think so.

Comment: why not @ClydeFrog ? how else are you going to answer the question?

Comment: Whatever a good answer might be, it won't need "thinghood" to reformulate events and reasons for events.

Comment: Doesn’t τ(x) ∧ ¬ρ(x) cover things that did not happen at all, whether with a reason or not?

Comment: @user3840170 The task of the thinghood predicate is, so to speak, to reduce 'everything' and 'nothing' to a common denominator; from a philosophical point of view, what to ascribe it to is directly related to one's metaphysical presumptions. One might ascribe thinghood to an idea, a possibility, etc. Whatever it is, one has to specify the same domain for both 'everything' and 'nothing'.

Answer (score 0):

1: Everything happens for a reason
2:nothing happens without a reason.

In 1, maybe Reason is there but nothing happens but in 2 there has to be a reason for things to happen.

I definitely see a difference between the two. So I translated the propositions into French and,again, perceived a difference between the two:
1 (il y a une raison pour tout) has a connotation of explanation. No randomness
but 2 (rien ne se passe sans une bonne raison) indicates that there has to be a reason for things to happen.